# Printing Hexadecimals as Hexadecimals in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, byte, hex

I need to send an array of bytes to a hardware (SDZ16 matrix) using a Serial Port. The trick is in the fact that that hardware expects strings of hexadecimal and ASCII characters.

When assigning values to the array of bytes, even if I set the bytes to an explicit hexadecimal value 
(`bytes[0] = 0xF2`, for instance), it will print the equivalent decimal value (242 instead of F2).

I am suspicious that the problem is in the `Console.WriteLine();` which when printing each byte sets them by default as integers(?) How does C# keep track that there is an Hexadecimal value inside an int?

If I assign `bytes[0] = 0xF2;` will the hardware understand it in hexadecimal even if `Console.WriteLine();` shows differently will testing?

Comment: No problem - you just haven't specified *how* you want the bytes formatted. Just because you used a hex literal instead of an integer literal doesn't mean the byte's value is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a string representation in hex format you can do so by using a corresponding [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
byte value = 0xF2;
string hexString = string.Format("{0:X2}", value);
```

Note that `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that takes a format string and a parameter list:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:X2}", value);
```

Update: I just had a glimpse at the documentation [here](http://www.elprovideolabs.com/docs/Elpro_SDZ16_user_manual_eng.pdf), and it seems that you need to send commands by providing the corresponding ASCII representation in the form of a string. You can get the ASCII representation using:

```
byte value = 0x01;
string textValue = value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textValue)
```

My tip would be to carefully check the documentation of your equipment to find out which exact format is expected.

Comment: Clarification: sending a byte array with hexadecimal values, will work? Int and Hex are both stored with the same values, and the reading format is what makes the difference. Is it the same with ASCII characters or they have different store values?

Comment: @ToniMarin: I don't know. What happens if you try?

Answer (score 0):

> it will print the equivalent decimal value (242 instead of F2).

Yes because `0xF2` is still `242`. It is just an [hexadecimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). Most comman prefix is `0x` in this notation. Even if you use debugger, you can see it's [decimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

[image]

> I am suspicious that the problem is in the Console.WriteLine(); which
>   when printing each byte sets them by default as integers(?)

No, [`Console.WriteLine()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console.WriteLine.aspx) nothing do here.

> How does C# keep track that there is an Hexadecimal value inside an
>   int?

There is no such a thing as *Hexadecimal value inside an int*. It is just a [notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation).

If you wanna hexadecimal notation of a number, you can use [The hexadecimal `"X"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#XFormatString) like;

```
byte b = 0xF2;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("X")); //F2
```

If you wanna get with prefix; you can do;

```
byte b = 0xF2;
Console.WriteLine("0x{0}", b.ToString("X")); //0xF2
```